# Probability - Airplane passengers

Tags: probability

In an airplane, 65% of the passengers liked to read. 23% liked to read and listen to music at the same time. 5% did not like to read or listen to music.

a) If a passenger is randomly selected from the flight, given that the passenger likes to listen to music, what is the probability that he/she likes to read during the flight?
b) What is the probability that a randomly selected passenger like to read or listen to music?

My Solution:

Read & listen to music = 23%
Read only = 65 - 23 % = 42%
Listen to music only = 30%
Neither read nor listen to music = 5%

a) P(Read/Music) = 23%/30%

b) P(Read or listen to music) = P(Read) + P(listen to music)/total
=42%+30%/100% = 72/100

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

P(read or listen) = P(read) + P(listen) - P(read $\cap$ listen). You need to find P(listen) to solve this. Draw a Venn diagram to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple.

Those that like both is 23%

Those that like to read is 65%. So those who like to read but hate music is 42%.

Those who don't like either is 5%. So 95% like either music or reading. Out of those 95%, 23% like both. So we're left with 72% people that like only music or only reading. So 72% like one and only one thing for our purpose.

42% only like reading.

So we got 30%=72%-42%

of people that like music and don't like reading.

If I can draw table
Like both 23%
Like none 5%
Like reading only 42%
Like music only 30%

You can check that the sum is 100%.

Because those who like both is 23%, we know that 65% like reading. And 53%=23%+30% like music.

From there you can check.